# vscode use react native tools run react native project , but adb devices /bin/sh: adb: command not found

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I use vscode extension run react native project
[image]

but console

```
[Error : 0101]  Failed to run the application in Android: Error while executing command 'adb devices': Command failed: adb devices /bin/sh: adb: command not found
```

I use terminal use `react-native run-android` , it can run , i write the config in .bash_profile and .zshrc file , how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I always meet with situation but after research I found a solution as below 
But make sure your have to restart your MAC OS

[image]